# Why is the Coroutine running once?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I'm having a situation whereby **the coroutine is executing once.** The second time I call the *fetchUser* function it does nothing:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = UserRepository(application)

    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user


    fun fetchUser(userId: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)  {
        val result = repository.getUser(userId)

        if (result.isSuccessfulWithData) {
            _user.postValue(result.data?.user)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean that calling `fetchUser` twice only executes it once? Have you defintiely verified that it never reaches the first line?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code, from where you call this. Please also mention how you are calling it multiple times?

Comment: Why are you using `Dispatchers.IO`? Isn't `repository.getUser` a suspendable function? Suspendable functions are safe to run on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, each time you `fetchUser` a new coroutine is launched and code inside it should execute each time. You can add `Log` at the beginning of the coroutine to check if the coroutine is launched in the Logcat. If `repository.getUser(userId)` is a `suspend` function I would also remove `Dispatchers.IO` context when calling `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` because it is safe to call `suspend` function in the `Dispatchers.Main` context (by default `viewModelScope` has `Dispatchers.Main` context). So the code with the `Log` and improvement will look like the following:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = UserRepository(application)

    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user


    fun fetchUser(userId: String) = viewModelScope.launch  {
        Log.d("UserViewModel", "fetchUser called")
        val result = repository.getUser(userId)

        if (result.isSuccessfulWithData) {
            _user.postValue(result.data?.user)
        }
    }
}
```